# How to include cmake dependencies from source for static use

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, visual-studio-2019

I'm currently writing an application which will make use of [OpenCV](https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git) and a few other dependencies using cmake. For the sake of the question only one dependency is relevant.

How can I construct a `CmakeLists.txt` file which downloads the OpenCV source from github and prepares it for static use within my application?

I have tried using `ExternalProject_Add` which looked promising until I realised the static libraries, etc are not available when they are needed (as far as i understand). I've had similar issues with `FetchContent_Declare` and related functions.

I understand I can build all my dependencies outside of the single `CmakeLists.txt` and use them with something like: `find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED PATHS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../build/opencv" )`. This works perfectly fine, however I'm hoping to have everything self contained within cmake so anyone that checks out my application wont have to do any special configuration or dependency fetching. Just `cmake build` and they would be ready to go.

**Note**:

I've tried many things and followed many blog posts over the past week to try and figure these things out. The post would be excruciatingly long if I were to document them all. At this point im very confused with how it should all work and im hoping someone can point out something obvious im missing.

I'm also aware i can use something like [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg) instead of compiling these applications from source. Due to the dependencies not listed I am not going down this route.

**Environment:**

- Windows 10
- Visual Studio 2019
- Cmake

**CmakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)

# set the project name
project(test-depends)
set(CMAKE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY "MultiThreaded$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:Debug>")
set(CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX d)

# Global settings
set(GLOBAL_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

# dependencies
include(ExternalProject)

## other dependencies are here
# ......

## OpenCV contrib
ExternalProject_Add(opencv_contrib
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib.git
    GIT_TAG 4.5.0
    BUILD_COMMAND ""
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)
ExternalProject_Get_Property(opencv_contrib SOURCE_DIR)
set(OPENCV_CONTRIB_SOURCE_DIR ${SOURCE_DIR})

# OpenCV
ExternalProject_Add(opencv
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
    GIT_TAG 4.5.0
    DEPENDS opencv_contrib # other dependencies omitted
    CMAKE_ARGS
        -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${GLOBAL_OUTPUT_PATH}/opencv
        -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF
        -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=${OPENCV_CONTRIB_SOURCE_DIR}/modules
        -DINSTALL_CREATE_DISTRIB=ON
        -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF
        -DWITH_CUDA=OFF
        -DBUILD_DOCS=OFF
        -DDENABLE_CXX11=ON
        -DDBUILD_TESTS=OFF
        -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF
)
ExternalProject_Get_Property(opencv SOURCE_DIR BINARY_DIR)
set(OPENCV_SOURCE_DIR ${SOURCE_DIR})
set(OPENCV_BINARY_DIR ${BINARY_DIR})

file(GLOB_RECURSE PROJECT_SOURCES "src/*.h" "src/*.cpp")
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_SOURCES})
set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 20)
add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} opencv)

include_directories(${GLOBAL_OUTPUT_PATH}/opencv/include)
target_link_directories( ${PROJECT_NAME}
    PRIVATE ${OPENCV_BINARY_DIR}/lib
)

set(OpenCV_LIBS "ade;opencv_aruco450d;opencv_bgsegm450d;opencv_bioinspired450d;opencv_calib3d450d;opencv_ccalib450d;opencv_core450d;opencv_datasets450d;opencv_dnn450d;opencv_dnn_objdetect450d;opencv_dnn_superres450d;opencv_dpm450d;opencv_face450d;opencv_features2d450d;opencv_flann450d;opencv_fuzzy450d;opencv_gapi450d;opencv_hfs450d;opencv_highgui450d;opencv_imgcodecs450d;opencv_imgproc450d;opencv_img_hash450d;opencv_intensity_transform450d;opencv_line_descriptor450d;opencv_mcc450d;opencv_ml450d;opencv_objdetect450d;opencv_optflow450d;opencv_phase_unwrapping450d;opencv_photo450d;opencv_plot450d;opencv_quality450d;opencv_rapid450d;opencv_reg450d;opencv_rgbd450d;opencv_saliency450d;opencv_shape450d;opencv_stereo450d;opencv_stitching450d;opencv_structured_light450d;opencv_superres450d;opencv_surface_matching450d;opencv_text450d;opencv_tracking450d;opencv_video450d;opencv_videoio450d;opencv_videostab450d;opencv_xfeatures2d450d;opencv_ximgproc450d;opencv_xobjdetect450d;opencv_xphoto450d;")

target_link_libraries(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    PRIVATE "${OpenCV_LIBS}"
)
```

**src/main.cpp**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

void main() {
    cv::Mat testing;
    std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: "I've tried many things and followed many blog posts over the past week to try and figure these things out. The post would be excruciatingly long if I were to document them all." - Actually, any approach you have listed could work: `ExternalProject_Add`, `FetchContent_Declare`, some mix of them, etc. Choose an approach and give more details about your attempt in that direction.

Comment: As far as i can tell, the ExternalProject_Add approach does not work (for what i want) since it doesn't have the sources available until a build is already attempted -- which is an issue. At this point im kind-of expecting to be told im using cmake incorrectly and im expecting apples from an orange tree. Is this the case? What makes ExternalProject_Add appropriate for what im trying to achieve here?

Comment: Declare also has its own problems i've seen..... For some reason it doesnt create a new entry in the solutions panel and instead combines everything together exacerbating confusion. [see this](https://i.imgur.com/OtcNAhb.png). I dont understand why this is -- but i suppose that's another question....

Ideally there's some kind of middle ground between the two and i don't have anything to show for it because im not even sure if its possible at this point

Comment: It is true that `ExternalProject_Add` performs download and compiling steps at the time when the main project is built. But **why** is it a problem for you? If you want to link your application with OpenCV libraries then link with to-be-created-libraries, and adjust appropriate **dependencies**, so OpenCV has already been built by `ExternalProject_Add` at the time when you application is linked. Well, it is hard to suggest more detailed description without viewing the part of `CMakeLists.txt` which builds your application.

Comment: I suggest that you investigate `vcpkg` a bit more, as your use case seems to fit with it perfectly and would make your code more portable and modular. The key takeaway is this: use CMake to make build, and vcpkg to manage your packages. In particular I  recommend that you investigate [Manfests mode](https://vcpkg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/specifications/manifests/).

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for your input -- clearly i've missed something.... I'll spend a bit more time and if necessary post a cmakelists if i'm still not able to figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: @Tsyvarev i've updated the question to include a CmakeLists.txt and a main.cpp. The project will not build due to linker issues which i'm not sure how to resolve right now. (findProject works however -- but it doesnt look like I can use that since the dependencies arent available at that time.).

I feel as though I'm going about this in a fundamentally flawed way. How should this work?

Comment: `find_package(OpenCV)` won't work for OpenCV if it is built using `ExternalProject_Add`. You need to fill `OpenCV_LIBS` variable **manually** using paths to OpenCV library files, created in the `OPENCV_BINARY_DIR` or `${GLOBAL_OUTPUT_PATH}/opencv` directories.

Comment: Surely theres a better way than to define all the libs manually, it seems like we're going about solving this issue the wrong way if we have to resort to this. Is there not a way to get cmake to do this whole process automatically? I would have thought there would be given how popular cmake is. I know it can under some circumstances -- i dont understand how this use-case is so much different that we NEED to do everything manually

Comment: This is why I was reluctant to post a CmakeLists -- it seems as though the direction I've started in was fundamentally flawed and as a result it has influenced the help I've received in a direction I was hoping to avoid.

Is it really not possible to have the following workflow (or similar) within cmake?

1. Fetch dependencies from source
2. Configure/do whats necessary automatically(eg, output static debug/release libs)
3. Have the equivalent of a find_project on the newly built dependency and have everything "just work" within my solution?

Thank you so much for your help so far too!